# Loading byte array as pdf in a div in a form (vb) without writing it to a file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to load byte array as pdf in a div in a form (vb). I can display to browser using  Response.BinaryWrite(byteArray). But I want to display in a div.

I also tried saving it to file and display that in pdf viewer. I am following example from https://gist.github.com/benvanderberg/8f5b9896fc1c35233b1e7bff69d9f58d

```
    function DisplayPDF() {
             var filePath = "C:\Examples\Test1.pdf";
             var adobeDCView = new AdobeDC.View({ clientId: ClientID, divId: "pdfdiv" });
             adobeDCView.previewFile({
                 content: { location: { url: filePath } },
                 metaData: { fileName: "Test1.pdf" }
             }, {});
         }
```

```
What is the best way to display directly from bytearray without saving to file? If its not possible, how to fix above code snippet?
```

Comment: Mozilla have written a javascript library that can render pdf pages into a canvas. Is that what you're looking for? https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/

Comment: I have not used pdf.js. I will look into it. I was curious as how people do a pdf preview programmatically without a file upload.